# Solutions to $z^3 - z^2- z =15 $

Tags: complex-numbers

Find in the form $a+bi$, all the solutions to the equation

$$z^3 - z^2- z =15 $$

I have no idea what to do - am I meant to factor out z to get $z(z^2-z-1)=15$ or should I plug in $a+bi$ to z?

Please help!!!!!!!

Comment: Every cubic has at least one real root.

Answer (score 6):

You are on the right track.

$$z^3 - z^2 - z -15 = 0$$
$$(z-3)(z^2 + 2z + 5) = 0$$

The first factor gives you a real root $r_1 = 3$

Now let's calculate the roots of the quadratic factor:

$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = -16 = 16i^2$

Since it is negative, you know that you have 2 complex conjugate roots of the form:
$\frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$

Thus

$r_2= -1 -2i$

$r_3 = -1+2i$

Comment: You should check your factorization.

Comment: My bad, fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Better, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Hint: First find the one real root, say $r$ (it's not hard). Then you can factor out $z-r$ out of $z^3-z^2-z-15=0$, and find the remaining roots using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Hey, I'd like to add that to find the first real root, a method I usually do is bring everything over to the left hand side then find the factors of the constant, in this case 15. So you would try 3 and 5, -3, -5. In this case, 3 works on the first try.

Comment: @KevinZ: Right.  By the rational root theorem, the possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 15$.

Answer (score 0):

Real solution:

$$z^3 - z^2- z =15<=> $$
$$z^3-z^2-z-15=0<=>$$
$$(z-3)(z^2+2z+5)=0<=>$$

So:

$$z-3=0<=>z=3$$
Or:
$$z^2+2z+5=0<=>z^2+2z=-5<=>z^2+2z+1=-4<=>(z+1)^2=-4$$
($(z+1)^2=-4$ hasno solution since for all $z$ on the real line, $(z+1)^2$ is bigger or even to zero and $-4$ is smaller than zero)

Complex solution:

$$z^3 - z^2- z =15<=> $$
$$z^3 - z^2- z -15=0<=>$$
$$(z-3)(z^2+2z+5)=0<=>$$

So:

$$z-3=0<=>z=3$$
Or:
$$z^2+2z+5=0<=>z^2+2z=-5<=>z^2+2z+1=-4<=>(z+1)^2=-4<=>$$

(the square root of both sides)

$$z+1=2i<=>z=-1+2i$$
Or:
$$z+1=-2i<=>z=-1-2i$$